# Selenium error message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="loginUsername"]"}

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium in python trying to test out logging in on tiktok. For some reason whenever I run my script it only enters the username, but I get the error Message:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="password"]"} for my password.
```

I know for sure that the password name is correct, and it has the exact same code as my username but for some reason only my username works?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "https://www.tiktok.com/login/phone-or-email/email"


username  = ""
password = ""

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get(url)

user = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
user.send_keys(username)

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
password.send_keys(password)

submit = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tiktok-15aypwy-Button-StyledButton")
submit.click()

print("logged in")
```

Comment: Why are you assuming its name is `password`? When I'm inspecting the website only the username has its name attribute set

Comment: You can use `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password']")` to get the password input :)

Comment: @Mandera Oh that makes sense I guess I read it wrong when inspecting. Thank you.